# React JS : Remove a part of a string in URL

Tags: reactjs, string, url, query-string

I am stuck at certain functionality.

let's say I have a URL as `www.myURL.com/myData`.

what I want is to remove **myData** from the URL but the component to be loaded will be **myData** component. so I just want to remove *myData* text from the URL but loads the **myData** component as it is.

I have tried **replace** and **remove** but it didn't work.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: can you plz post some of the codes you tried so far

Comment: Well firstly, when you walk about 'loading a component', we'll need some code to see exactly what that means, since that sounds weird. But also, loading React components based on URL sounds _super_ weird, why are you taking that approach?

Comment: @Jayce444 . basically the thing is.. in my React application , I have my route.And when I hit the URL **www.myURL.com/myData** then I get the Tracking Page for that. but I want it to be loaded on **www.myURL.com* not on **www.myURL.com/myData** . here **www.myURL.com** will be dynamic. custom domain might be there for that. so If someone has a custom domain as **test.tracking.com** then **/myData** component must be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-router-dom` you can use it like this:

```
<Redirect from='/users/:id' to='/users'/>
<Route path='/users' component={Users} />
```

And now everytime you have something like `/users/some-id` it will redirect to `/users`.

And if you want to access `/users` when you are on `/`

You can do this

```
<Route path='/users' component={Users} />
<Route path='/' component={Users} />
```

So now even when you access `/` it will load `Users Component`

Comment: thank you for your comment. I would like to clear the thing that if I hit the URL like 
**www.myURL.com** then it should load the component of *www.myURL.com/myData* .

Comment: basically the thing is.. in my React application , I have my route.And when I hit the URL www.myURL.com/myData then I get the Tracking Page for that. but I want it to be loaded on www.myURL.com* not on **www.myURL.com/myData . here www.myURL.com will be dynamic. custom domain might be there for that. so If someone has a custom domain as test.tracking.com then /myData component must be loaded.

Comment: Then you should handle it in `NGINX` or whatever you are using to run your app!